# What is meant by an "optional" postgres support function?

Tags: postgresql

The GIST `distance` support function, according to the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xindex.html#XINDEX-GIST-SUPPORT-TABLE), is "optional".  What exactly does "optional" mean for something like this?

Comment: Probably that the index can be built and queried without it, but might be more efficient when the function is provided.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not defined, then you can't use the index for [ordering ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xindex.html#XINDEX-ORDERING-OPS), which are described further down on the same page.  But you can still use it for search ops.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  How does one ensure a support function is defined?  For use the GIST index for the "<->" operator, how can I ensure I have a "distance" function defined?